# How to use ray to efficiently run inference onnx run time?

Tags: multiprocessing, ray, onnxruntime

I am running my inference scripts with multiprocessing currently which takes up a lot of memory with loading models with onnxruntime so I am trying to use ray run inference but getting issue with speed
this is the code I am using Kindly help me figure where I am might be doing my implementation wrong and suggest a better method to optimize the inference

```
import ray
import onnxruntime as ort
import numpy as np

    @ray.remote
    class ModelActor:
        def __init__(self, model_path):
            self.session = ort.InferenceSession(model_path)
    
        def run(self, inputs):
            try:
                return self.session.run(None, inputs)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return None
    
    def create_actors(model_paths):
        return {model_name: ModelActor.remote(model_path) for model_name, model_path in model_paths.items()}
    
    @ray.remote
    def run_inference(args, actor_ids):
        image_path, model_config = args
        actors = {name: ray.get_actor(name) for name in actor_ids}
    
        output = {}
        exceptions = []
    
        try:
            for model_name, model_info in model_config['models'].items():
                if model_name in actors:
                    model_actor = actors[model_name]
    
                    inputs = load_image(image_path)
                    future = model_actor.run.remote(inputs)
                    result = ray.get(future)
    
                    output[model_name] = result
    
        except Exception as e:
            exceptions.append(e)
    
        return output, exceptions
    
    def run_inference_ray(args):
        model_config = args['model_config']
        image_paths = args['image_paths']
    
        ray.init()  
    
        actors = create_actors(model_config)  
    
        actor_ids = [actor._actor_id for actor in actors.values()]
    
        args_list = [(image_path, model_config) for image_path in image_paths]
    
        tasks = [run_inference.remote(arg, actor_ids) for arg in args_list]
    
        results = ray.get(tasks)
    
        print(results)
```